# How to add additional IO under certain condition to RoCCIO in Chisel

Tags: riscv, chisel

I am trying to add custom instruction to RISC-V by using ROCC, and my base is the rocket-chip.
Some of the accelerators requires additional IO to be added to the RoCCIO class.
I am trying to understand the conditional instantiation of additional IO's, like in the case of the Floating point unit & page table walker (PTW) ,I am new to Chisel & Scala so it very cryptic to me.

Can someone explain how this code implement conditional instantiation:

```
    class RoCCIO(outer: LazyRoCC)(implicit p: Parameters) extends RoCCCoreIO()(p) {
       val ptw = Vec(p(RoccNPTWPorts), new TLBPTWIO)
       val fpu_req = Decoupled(new FPInput)
       val fpu_resp = Decoupled(new FPResult).flip
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of RoCC is using dead code elimination (however, you must be careful to tie off the signals you aren't using just to be sure).

You can instead use Option to perform conditional instantiation in your IO bundle declaration:

```
val a = if (cond) Some(UInt(width=5.W)) else None
```

Comment: This line seems not working because the `None` type is `object` rather than chisel3.Data.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably better suited for the rocket-chip repository so those developers will see it: https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/issues

That being said, there are a couple of ways things can be conditionally instantiated in Chisel code.

1. Inheritance: when a Bundle extends another Bundle it can add additional fields, thus the inclusion of those fields is conditional upon which Bundle is actually being instantiated
2. Dead Code Elimination: Chisel/FIRRTL has robust Dead Code Elimination so if some ports are unused they will simply be removed. Thus the fields can be conditionally removed in configurations that do not use them. **I believe this is the case here** (but am unsure).